# How do I make Windows 7 display SSID Unicode characters correctly in the Network panel?

Tags: windows-7, networking, unicode

On Windows 7 Unicode characters are displayed correctly everywhere except on the Wifi settings and network options panel. More specifically it's the SSID of my home network that has an "é" (French acute accent on e) character in it that is replaced by jumbled characters (not the usual empty rectangles).
Other operating systems (android, OS X, even Linux) don't have this problem with my Wifi so I am 95% it has something to do with Windows.
Curiously enough I haven't been able to find a solution to this ultra-specific problem online so I now turn to you guys!
It's not that big a problem at all but for some reason it's driving me batty and I'm curious as to what is causing the issue.

kind regards

Comment: Are you sure this is Unicode? It can also be extended ASCII, and the use of different codepages will result in different characters to be shown. Actually, I think this issue would not appear on Unicode at all.

Comment: «*even Linux*» — funny sentence, with regard to a «toolbox-OS». I do know what the problem though: the systems you mentioned, GNU/Linux, Android which is Linux based, and OS X which is a unix — they use UTF8. Windows is the single OS which uses deprecated UTF16 by default. So, encoding mismatch is what breaks it. I don't know if there's a way to fix that *(except of using aside app)* though.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 cannot display unicode ssid's. Last time I checked you would have change source code.

Comment: @Mureinik "It cannot be done" is a valid answer :)